# What is the significance of implicit calculate in summarise vs groupby?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm learning summarise vs groupby and the documentation specified that

> Unlike the SUMMARIZE function, an implied CALCULATE is not performed,
> and the group isn't placed into the filter context

Generally an implied calculate means context transition. Can someone give me an example to understand how this concept applies to summarize vs groupby?

If group isn't placed in filter context then how does is the result grouped by the respective group?